# R Using exponential regression equation

Tags: r

I want to use a variable in loop like this;

```
for(i_want_to_use_this in seq(1,8)){
lm(
  y ~ (
    PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 + PC5 + PC6 + PC7 +PC8
  )^i_want_to_use_this ,
  data = as.data.frame(transformed2)
)
}
```

I have tried a lot of things, but I wasn't able to do this.Is there anybody have any idea for about this?

```
 y ~ PC1 + PC2 + ... + PC8 + PC1:PC2+PC1:PC3+...+PC1:PC8+...+PC1:PC2:..:PC8
```

thanks a lot.

### Edit

I am getting below error.

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid power in
>   formula

Comment: Not clear.  What `y ~ (PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 + PC5 + PC6 + PC7 +PC8)^i` is supposed to mean ?

Comment: @jogo Thanks for your interest. I know I am not saving result. 
I tried your code and I got 'Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid power in formula' this error.

Comment: @jogo Actually I want this equation;
y ~ PC1 + PC2 + ... + PC8 + PC1:PC2+PC1:PC3+...+PC1:PC9+...+PC1:PC2:..:PC9

Comment: `lm(mpg ~ (cyl+hp+drat)^1, data=mtcars);
lm(mpg ~ (cyl+hp+drat)^2, data=mtcars);
lm(mpg ~ (cyl+hp+drat)^3, data=mtcars)` the first produces the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it looks like the problem would be ^1 in a formula.

try this:

```
for(i_want_to_use_this in seq(1,8)){
form = if(i_want_to_use_this < 2) formula("y ~ (PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 + PC5 + PC6 + PC7 +PC8)") else formula(paste0("y ~ (PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 + PC5 + PC6 + PC7 +PC8)^",i_want_to_use_this))

lm(form, data = as.data.frame(transformed2))
}
```

or, using your code with a little adaption:

edit to this answer:

```
PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 + PC5 + PC6 + PC7 +PC8
      )^i_want_to_use_this
```

this doesn't work as a formular, since it is used as a pure string (i_want_to_use_this is not transformed into its numeric value).

one has to paste it together:

```
paste0("PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 + PC5 + PC6 + PC7 +PC8
      )^",i_want_to_use_this)
```

this way `i_want_to_use_this` is replaced by the number it contains

```
lm(
  y ~ (
    PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 + PC5 + PC6 + PC7 +PC8
  ),
  data = as.data.frame(transformed2)
)

for(i_want_to_use_this in seq(2,8)){
lm(
  y ~ (
    paste0("PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + PC4 + PC5 + PC6 + PC7 +PC8
  )^",i_want_to_use_this),
  data = as.data.frame(transformed2)
)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution;

```
lm(
  paste0("y~(PC1+PC2+PC3+PC4+PC5)^",i),
  data = as.data.frame(transformed2)
)
```

### Edit for @jogo

```
for(i in seq(2,10)){

  abc <-
    model.matrix(lm(
      paste0("y~(anode + augiris + btb + elution + ewc + nacn + naoh + flow + loadcar+ saat_no)^",i),
      data = as.data.frame(saat)
    ))
  x <- (abc[, 2:length(colnames(abc))])

  # print(head(x,2))
  lambdas <- 10 ^ seq(3,-2, by = -.1)
  for (alp in seq(0, 1, 0.01)) {
    cv_fit <- cv.glmnet(x,
                        y,
                        alpha = alp,
                        lambda = lambdas)
    opt_lambda <- cv_fit$lambda.min
    fit <- cv_fit$glmnet.fit
    y_predicted <-
      predict(fit, s = opt_lambda, newx = x)

    # Sum of Squares Total and Error
    sst <- sum((y - mean(y)) ^ 2)
    sse <- sum((y_predicted - y) ^ 2)

    # R squared
    rsq <- 1 - sse / sst


    if (se_last > sse) {
      se_last <- sse
      rsq_son <- rsq
      y_predicted_son <- y_predicted
      y_son <- y
      alp_son<-alp
      fit_son <- fit
      opt_lambda_son <- opt_lambda
      i_son<-i
      print(paste0(i, "-",alp, "-", rsq))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `i <- 1;
lm( paste0("mpg ~ (cyl+hp+drat)^",i), data=mtcars)` produces the same error.

Comment: This works for me, but someone gave me -1 , this is really weird!

Comment: @jogo You can see my all script.

Comment: Thank you; so it is clear that you simply are not using the value i=1 in your formula (...)^i (which was your problem). The answer from @TinglTanglBob gives a clear description about the error and how to work around. If you would accept the answer of TinglTanglBob you would even get some +reputation (accepting the own answer gives no +reputation).